# How to enable auto suspend to RAM on ReadyNAS 104?

Tags: nas, wake-on-lan, suspend, readynas

I've recently bought a ReadyNAS 104 and I want to save energy by suspending it to RAM. This should be done automatically after a user defined idle time. How do I configure the NAS do behave in this way. Of course the NAS shall wake up if receiving WOL packets. This works already.

I didn't find any option on the web interface of the NAS. Is there any plug-in (app) I can install or do I have to alter the system over SSH?

Comment: Nobody who configured their system like I want to do? Thanks to the serverfault moderators to force me to move the question to this Q&A site. :-(

Comment: I'm really disappointed! No answers, not even one comment. Is the question not understandable? Should I reword it? Should I ask it again on serverfault?

Comment: Typically most people leave their NAS running, the idea is they are low usage already so leaving them going isnt really an issue. Its rated at 45W which is reasonably low.